# Can i run Stored function on GreenPlum or Postgres sql using NIFI? If Yes then which processor and what configurations should i use?

Tags: apache-nifi, greenplum

> How i can run *stored functions or Procedures* on **Greenplum/Postgres** SQL using Nifi?

Comment: You probably need PutSQL, but what exactly do you want to use the stored procedures for?

Comment: @A.Scherbaum - My stored Procedure doing multiple things like - Creating temp tables, Cleaning data , temp variables - select data etc.

Answer (score 1):

Had run into a similar situation as well.
To do this, you create the stored procedure within PostgreSQL.

Once done, you can use the ExecuteSQL processor to run the procedure as such:

```
select stored_procedure_name();
```

Hope that helps.